# Laravel image validation failed

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

This code worked in my local but not on live server, on live server some images cannot be uploaded but some can but i can't see the difference between the images.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');

$this->middleware('auth');

$this->validate($request, [
    'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5120',
    'description' => 'required'
]);

$image_name = 'IMG'.time().'_'.rand(1000,9999);
$image_name_thumb = $image_name."_thumb";
$extension = ".".$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$image_name_ext = $image_name.$extension;
$image_name_thumb_ext = $image_name_thumb.$extension;
$request->image->move(public_path('images/wall/'), $image_name_ext);
$img = Image::make(public_path('images/wall/'.$image_name_ext));
$img->resize(250, null, function ($constraint) { $constraint->aspectRatio();});
$img->save(public_path('images/wall/'.$image_name_thumb_ext));
```

This is the error message returned by

```
$errors->first('image')
```

"The image failed to upload."

Comment: It seems your validation is correct. Share uploading code also, and ensure that you have allowed folder to store.

Comment: do you have any errors in your log?

Comment: @prolapse : he is getting `"The image failed to upload."`

Comment: @Niklesh Updated with upload codes, folder permission is not the problem, some images can be uploaded, the below upload code is not executed though because if i exit; after validation nothing happens.

Comment: @prola No there are no errors in my log file

Comment: Have you verified that image size isn't the issue?  The upload_max_filesize and/or post_max_size may be set differently on the live server in php.ini.

Comment: @alaric same issue. When image is bigger than max size set Laravel returns "The image failed to upload". Seems like you should be able to change or customize the message to be proper. Haven't figured this out.